# Cross-Sell in python after finding similar users based on their product purchases

Tags: python, machine-learning, collaborative-filtering

I have the data in the below format :

```
CustomerID P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7
C1         0  1  1  0  1  0  0
C2         0  0  1  0  1  0  0
C3         0  0  1  0  0  1  0
C4         0  0  0  0  1  0  0
C5         0  0  0  0  1  1  0
C6         0  1  0  0  1  0  1
```

0 and 1 are the flags for whether customer bought that product or not

I want to find similar users based on their purchases and finally recommend the next product to them. And validate the results as well.

How can I do this in python ?

Comment: try using apriori algorithm :3

Comment: apriori will give me similar products , how will i decide on similar users ?

Comment: In simple case, You can find correlation between users and recommend the highest correlated user's choice of product to him. But it will be better if you check for different Collaborative Filtering Based Methods for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have researched a lot and came up with the below algorithms to find the similarity between the customers/users.

1. Jaccard indexing (not feasible for large data sets)
2. MinHash (more efficient than Jaccard indexing but still takes time for large data sets)
3. Clustering machine learning algorithm(Only works well with data that could be clustered 
   in a round shape. Your data cannot make a round shape clusters when you plot them )
4. User collaborative filtering is what I found the most efficient one. We could use cosine similarity between the customers and products and then use KNN algorithm to predict.
5. NCF - Neural networks Collaborative Filtering.

Comment: Also, I am currently working on the same problem, same data set as yours but I have more than 1 million records. So, I am trying to find the code for cosine similarity